# Receiving response from socket to Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, broadcastreceiver, android-service

There are many similar questions, but i did not manage to find one that matches my case so here it goes. I have a service, which receives data and sends data back to activities using Broadcast Receiver. The problem comes when i use activity that is set up with tab views that supports Android API 8 and higher (With App Compat Library). I successfully send a request to the Service from the Fragment Class which is done by pressing a button inside the layout file which is used only for the selected tab in activity and is linked to the java class. However, my initialized Broadcast Receiver does not catch the broadcast from the Service. My current code displayed below.

Fragment Class

```
public class ConfigFragmentGeneral extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
EditText dsi, dsimaxd, dsimind, dsmaxa, dsiis, adc1diff, adc2diff, adc3diff, adc4diff, adc1level, adc2level, adc3level, adc4level;
Button send, save, delete;
Spinner presetSpinner;
View fragmentView;

ArrayAdapter<String> presetAdapter;
List<String> presetArray, presetNamesArray;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_config_general, container, false);

    ..........

    return fragmentView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.sendGeneral:

            if (isAllowedToSave())
            {
                  ///////////Intent to the Service
                final String confValues ="some values";

                OtherActivity.socketIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SocketService.class);
                OtherActivity.socketIntent.putExtra("type", 12);
                OtherActivity.socketIntent.putExtra("config_values", confValues);
                getActivity().startService(Pagrindinis.socketIntent);
            }

            break;
```

Activity where the tabbed fragments are displayed, BroadcastReceiver is also here

```
public class Config extends ActionBarActivity{
ActionBar actionBar;
private ViewPager viewPager;

static boolean mBound = false;
static SocketService mService;

public static final String RECEIVE_SET_CONFIG = "something.whatever";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_config);

    actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

    ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener pageChangeListener = new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener()
    {
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    };

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(pageChangeListener);

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(fragmentManager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

    ActionBar.TabListener tabListener = new ActionBar.TabListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction)
        {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {}
    };

    Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("One Tab")
            .setTabListener(tabListener);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);

    tab = actionBar.newTab()
            .setText("Another Tab")
            .setTabListener(tabListener);

    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    super.onBackPressed();
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_right_in,R.anim.slide_left_out);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();

    unbindService(mConnection);
    unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    mBound = false;
}

@Override
public void onResume()
{
    super.onResume();

    Pagrindinis.socketIntent = new Intent(this, SocketService.class);
    bindService(Pagrindinis.socketIntent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentFilter.addAction("RECEIVE_SET_CONFIG");
    registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, intentFilter);
    mBound = true;

    Log.v("DEV","onResume");
}

public static ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection()
{
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service)
    {
        SocketService.SocketBinder binder = (SocketService.SocketBinder) service;
        mService = binder.getService();
        mBound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name)
    {
        mBound = false;
    }
};

public static BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.getAction().equals(RECEIVE_SET_CONFIG))
        {
            Log.v("DEV", "CONFIG RESPONSE BROADCAST RECEIVER");

            //Toast.makeText(this, intent.getExtras().getString("response"), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
{
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.config, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)
{
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

Socket Class Thread

```
else if ((temp.equals("somecase")) && ((type == 12)))
                    {
                        StringTokenizer extraFilter = new StringTokenizer(filterToken.nextToken(),":");
                        if (extraFilter.hasMoreTokens()) temp = extraFilter.nextToken();

                        if (temp.equals(something))
                        {
                            temp = extraFilter.nextToken();

                            Intent ret = new Intent();
                            ret.setAction(Config.RECEIVE_SET_CONFIG);
                            ret.putExtra("response", temp);
                            sendBroadcast(ret);

                            Log.v("DEV","forwarded SET CONFIG");
                        }
                    }
```

I have also tried to move Broadcast Receiver (together with onStart and onStop) to the Fragment class, but same result was achieved. Any Ideas how i can access the broadcast sent from the Socket in the fragment class? Or maybe I am sending the broadcast from Socket not the proper way? Thanks

Comment: why not to use bound services?

Comment: psink can you explain more about bound services?

Comment: read this article http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

Comment: @pskink I am already using bound services. If you check my code above, I am binding activity to the service already. I also tried to bind each fragment class separately but it did not work as well.

Comment: so if you are bound ti your Service why do you use a BrodcastReceiver and not a IBinder returned by your Service?

Comment: I used BroadcastReceiver because it is not very clear (for me) how to use IBinder. The link to android guide to bound services is not explained enough as well how to use that Messenger for this purpose (which is what you are talking about i think?). Any chance you could explain how could IBinder be used in this situation?

Comment: your service is a local one right? then read this http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder

Comment: The problem with this example is that i do not want to return from the service (this example would quit the method which is called). The purpose of the service is to connect to the socket and be open, wait for particular responses from the server. The time, when response from service to fragment class is sent, depends on when the server gives the particular response for the socket. So in my situation requests for the service and responses from the socket are handled in different threads (Since i need socket connection Thread to stay open). Not sure if i am clear enough about my situation?